# Get Parent and then Child objects conditionally

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-objects

I have a list of objects with the following basic structure:

```
class Person
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public bool ShowChildren {get; set;}
    public int ParentID {get; set;}

    // ...many other properties...
}
```

I need to return a list of Person parent classes that are orderd by their ID. If the ShowChildren flag is enabled, also return the children under their parent, ordered by their ID.

This is only one level deep, i.e. children won't have children.

I can write a linq statement to give me all of the parents, but I'm stuck on how to also include the sorted children when the parent's flag is enabled.

```
var People = PersonList
             .Where(x => x.ParentID == 0)
             .Orderby(x => x.ID)
             .ToList();
```

Comment: Do you just want a flat list of all parents and relevant children, or do you want a heirarchy where the children are somehow "under" their parents?

Comment: The final sorting of the list should be only by the self ID or ParentID and then self ID? I mean, should children come always after its parents?

Comment: You want the returned object to be a List, with children immediately following their parent?

Comment: The resulting list is going to be bound to a dataview, which needs to be in parent-child order. So the resulting list should be sorted by Parents, and then by children under each parent. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, if you only want to return parents unless explicitly requested (thanks, @Rawling!), a `foreach` loop is also nice.

```
var people = new List<Person>();

PersonList.Sort((a, b) => a.ID - b.ID);

foreach(Person p in PersonList) {
    if(p.ParentID == 0) { // Or whatever value you use to represent it
        people.Add(p);

        if(p.ShowChildren) {
            people.AddRange(PersonList.Where(c => c.ParentID == p.ID));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code will lead to every item being added at least once, and children being added a second time if their parent deigns to show them.

Comment: @Rawling: Yes, that's what I took the question to mean. What do you think it should look like instead? :|

Comment: I read "I need to return a list of Person parent classes..." to mean include all the parents, and the children only if the parent wants them. So you'd only iterate over the parents, not all the items. Also, this doesn't do any sorting...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in *two* statements as follows:

```
// Build a lookup: parent ID => whether to show children.
var showChildrenDictionary = PersonList
    .Where(p => p.ParentID = 0)
    .ToDictionary(p => p.ID, p => p.ShowChildren);

// Get the desired list
var orderdedWithAppropriateChildren = PersonList
    // Discard children where not shown
    .Where(p => p.ParentID == 0 || showChildrenDictionary[p.ParentID])
    // Sort so parents and children are together and ordered by the parent
    .OrderBy(p => ((p.ParentID == 0) ? p.ID : p.ParentID))
    // Sort so parent is at start of group
    .ThenBy(p => p.ParentID != 0)
    // Sort so children are in order
    .ThenBy(p => p.ID)
    .ToList();
```